# Error attaching DB file with 'update-database'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

**ERROR:  Cannot attach the file 'C:\Projects\eManager2\eManager.Web\App_Data\eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb.mdf' as database**

**Connection string in Web.Config:**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SFP\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-eManager.Web-20131001100714;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-eManager.Web-20131001100714.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**MVC Entity Framework Configuration.cs class  in Migrations folder:**

```
namespace eManager.Web.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb context)
        {
            context.Departments.AddOrUpdate
                (
                    d => d.Name,
                    new Domain.Department() { Name = "Engineering" },
                    new Domain.Department() { Name = "Sales" },
                    new Domain.Department() { Name = "Marketing" },
                    new Domain.Department() { Name = "Human Resources" }
                );
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that "20131001100714.mdf" is the same as the migration you added.